# CGRect for frame of UINavigationController + Status Bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, cagradientlayer

I am working on adding a gradient behind my NavigationBar. I subclassed UINavigationController to do so. The gradient should fill both the status bar and UINavigationBar. The issue is I can only get it to fill the UINavigationBar (via self.toolBar.bounds). *I tried adding the height of the status bar, but it didn't allow for +*

```
@IBOutlet weak var toolBar: UINavigationBar!
```

---

```
let gradient:CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradient.frame = self.toolBar.bounds
gradient.colors = [UIColor.greenColor().CGColor, UIColor.blueColor().CGColor]
self.toolBar.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, atIndex: 1)
toolBar.barTintColor = UIColor.grayColor()
```

**Here's a screenshot of what the above code is producing:**
[image: Gradient is filling the wrong frame.]

The gradient should extend up into the status bar, so there will be no grayColor.

Comment: you can try to set UIStatusBarStyleLightContent property to remove gray color

Comment: @JP_Mob - It already is set to that. The gray is explicitly set in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting gradient to `UINavigationBar. Navigation bar's size is`44`and it's y position is`20` if status bar is there. So if you set gradient to navigation bar then definitely it set on it only. It definitely not affect status bar because it is different thing.

In your case you should make custom navigation bar i think by using `UIView`.

Just hide default navigation bar for particular this view controller and drag uiview of size `64` and put at `(0,0)`, so it covers both status bar and navigation bar space.

And set gradient to that view and you will come to desired effect you want.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: That makes sense. I didn't think of doing that. Is creating your own navigation bar's common in Xcode / swift?

Comment: yeah it's common. Most people uses custom navigation bar like this

Comment: I'm currently embedding my UITableViewController in a navigation controller. If I were to make my own view that will serve as the Navigation Bar, do I not need to embed in navigation controller anymore? I can just delete the embedded nav controller, and then just set the constraints manually, correct?

Comment: No you required navigartion controller to push and pop viewcontroller on it. to maintain navigation stack. you just use custom view instead of navigation bar and hide original one.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Do you have any StackOverflow links that have this explained in a step-by-step process?

Comment: You're welcome... just google it you will got many solutions..:)

Comment: I think I have it all figured out! I clicked the Navigation Controller > Navigation Bar. Then hid it. Then on my other 2 view controllers that use the navigation controller, I dragged 2 views in each at 64 px tall. Is this what you instructed me to do?

Comment: Nevermind my previous question. I am good now! I just used UINavigationControllernavigationBarHidden to hide the nav bar on all my views. Works like a charm!!

Answer (score -1):

You can provide image also for gradient:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gradiant_bg"]]];
```